# Open a file specified in a QLabel

Tags: c++, qt, file, label

I want to put in a label the direction of the file then click a button and open it in another label :

```
QFile file("/Users/Ignacio/Documents/3 curso/segundo semestre/cafeteria-2/txt/HEREGOESTHEFILE.txt");

 if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
     QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());
    QTextStream in (&file);
     ui->cajagrande->setText(in.readAll());
```

So I tried something like this

```
Char a [] = ui->label->text();
QFile file(a);

 if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
     QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());
    QTextStream in (&file);
     ui->cajagrande->setText(in.readAll());
```

but it dosen't work.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?  Also "`Char a [] = ui->label->text()`" is obviously wrong -- try "`QString a = ui->label->text()`".

Comment: It is always important to give as many details as possible regarding an error - What do you see? any messages? logs?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful that you were using the file even on errors, place braces correctly as well as the `else` clause.

```
QFile file(ui->label->text());

if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
  QMessageBox::information(0, "info", file.errorString());
} else {
  QTextStream in(&file);
  ui->cajagrande->setText(in.readAll());
}
```

*Note:* a `QFile` can be open directly with a filename given as `QString`, no need to converting to a pointer of chars.